# ListView of objects updated asynchronously

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a ListView that displays a list of objects received by an event handler function. Objects are received asynchronously and one at a time (similar to [ListViewDataSource documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html)'s scenario).

Each object has an ID and a value field (among others irrelevant here).
The ListView would display both fields for each object.

The handler can receive multiple objects with the same ID, but different values. In this case, the ListView should update the entry with the new value.

Inserting new items to the ListView work fine, But I updating existing items does not. How to do it?

Follow up question: What if I want to sort the elements in the ListView by the value field? What's the best way to do it?

Pseudo(ish) code for the Object:

```
class DataObj {
  objid: string;
  value: string;

  static create(rawData: string) : ?DataObj {
    if (Invalid data) return null;

    let dataObj = new DataObj();
    dataObj.objid = ...;
    dataObj.value = ...;
    return dataObj;
  }

  static equal(lhs: DataObj, rhs: DataObj) {
    return (lhs.objid === rhs.objid && lhs.value === rhs.value);
  }
}
```

Code for the component:

```
type State = {
  items: ListView.DataSource,
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state: State;

  _items = {};

  constructor(props: Props, context: {}) {
    super(props, context);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => !DataObj.equal(r1, r2)
    });
    this.state = {
      items: ds.cloneWithRows(this._items),
    };
  }

  _onNewItem = async (rawData: string) => {
    const newItem = DataObj.create(rawData);
    if (newItem) {
      // Valid item
      let oldItem = this._items[newItem.objid];
      if (!old || !DataObj.equal(oldItem, newItem)) {
        // New item or updated item
        // Clone _items, since it must be immutable, and add new item to it.
        let newItems = Object.assign({}, this._items);
        newItems[newItem.objid] = newItem;
        // update _items reference to its modified clone.
        this._items = newItems;
        // Update the state
        this.setState(({items}) => ({
          items: items.cloneWithRows(newItems),
        }));
      }
    }
  };

  render(): React.Element<*> {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.items}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        renderRow={this._renderDataObj} />
    );
  }

  _renderDataObj = (
    obj: DataObj,
    sectionID: number,
    rowID: number
  ) : React.Element<*> => {
    return (
      <DataObjRenderer
        key={obj.objid}
        objid={obj.objid}
        value={obj.value}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is partially possible to solve the problem using ListView.
The key property of items must include all properties that would cause a re-render.

However, the best solution is using FlatList, which replaces the soon-to-be-deprecated ListView.
Using the same key trick with FlatList solved all problems I had.

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3C documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp), you can sort an array as follows:

```
const points = [
    {
        name: 'Alpha',
        score: 40
    },
    {
        name: 'Bravo',
        score: 100
    },
    {
        name: 'Charlie',
        score: 1
    }
];

points.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.score - b.score;
});
```

Using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4), it would be cleaner:

```
_.orderBy(points, ['user', 'age'],
```

Comment: Indeed it sorts the array. The followup question would be about using a map to store the objects and update them as necessary. Then it would be necessary to get an array with its items: Array.from(this._items.values()). Then sorting it. However it causes another problem: React ignores when I change properties of a DataObject. I tried adding all "observable" properties to the key of the ListView element. However it also doesn't work well.